# Two different LDR circuits: what's the fundamental difference?

Tags: photoresistor

[image]

Here’s what’s going on. I’m working on a programmable light timer (of course I could use something like Alexa, but I’d rather go for the challenge and build something to my own design), where the LDR node will be pulled low upon a low resistance of R3, when it’s illuminated. This node is an input to a microcontroller.
Circuit 1 one seems simple, and is easy to understand: conduction through the LDR turns on Q1, and the current through the CE junction is enough to bring the LDR / collector node ordinarily held high, now low, and toggles the microcontroller.
Circuit 2 is a slightly modified Heathkit light-sensitive lamp switch, circa 1974. In the original circuit, Instead of R5, Q2 brings a relay to ground, turning on the switched load. But why does it tie the base circuit of Q1 into the emitter circuit of Q2? What’s to gain? I know the circuit works with the relay in place of R5, but I’m curious about the topology.
Hoping for some help! I seem to have forgotten my most basic electronic skills from my undergrad days, and no longer have access to my notes, homework, or even the textbook.

Comment: You write that you want to *"build something to my own design."* This seems to say that you want to design something and **then** build it. To design something, you need to write down what you want to achieve. For example, do you want to be able to vary the threshold in a way that makes sense with respect to human brightness perception? Do you want to include hysteresis and positive feedback so that the circuit switches states and does so quickly but without "chatter" when the light levels are near the threshold you set? Etc. All must be carefully considered and written down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second circuit uses feedback to create hysteresis. When the transistors switch on, the voltage across R6 goes up, this is fed back to the LDR so that its resistance has to change more to shut the transistors back off than if it was just grounded as in the first circuit.

This is so that when it gets dark enough for the LDR circuit to turn on the lamp, the light from the lamp doesn't then cause it to shut right back off again.

Comment: Of course! Would that I could have seen that. Makes perfect sense, but I'll prototype both of them just to see what happens. Thank you, GodJihyo!